# What lubuntu chose amd64 or i386

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, 64-bit

I have the Intel Atom® Processor N450 (supports x64 but its not amd processor) on my netbook but here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.2/release/ says:  If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the i386 images instead. Choose this if you are at all unsure.

Comment: intel-64 bit is an amd class processor. instal the amd64 version

Comment: It should say "If You have CPU which doesn't support 64-bit mode, use i386 images.". In most cases if Your CPU supports 64-bit mode, You should use x64 image. I don't know what they tried to say by "if You need 32-bit full support for code". In 2017 You never need "full" support for 32-bit code.You just using 64-bit OS, and 99.99% of apps have and run their 64-bit binaries, which work better in 64-bit having access to additional 64-bit CPU instructions. The only disadvantage of 64-bit mode is: on some PCs with low RAM (<=1GB) 32-bit OS may work better, it usually uses less RAM than 64-bit OS.

Comment: I repeat the end of @NoAngel's comment:  "The only disadvantage of 64-bit mode is: on some PCs with low RAM (<=1GB) 32-bit OS may work better, it usually uses less RAM than 64-bit OS", which might be the case here. How much RAM is there is your netbook computer, Nacho? If only 1GB RAM, I suggest using the i386 version.

Comment: Thanks! Okey. I have 1GB RAM. So i must install the i386 version.

Answer (score 3):

AMD64 is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set. Intel support AMD64. The 64-bit version is recommended version, mainly because 32-bit only supports 4GB of RAM. As your computer supports 64-bit, you should use 64-bit.

Comment: Ok, but i have only 1GB RAM. :/